# useState has previous value instead of the current

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm new to react and I'm trying to understand how it's working.

I have 2 select inputs and on change event I want to filter the other's select values based on the first one.

After calling `setOptions` with the filtered values, they are always one step behind - so I have the previous value each time.

I understand that useState is async and I tried with and `useEffect (() => {}, [options])`
and I still have the previous values in options.

```
 const [options, setOptions] = useState<any>()
 const filterOptions = (ids: string[]) => {
        const filteredOptions = list.filter(item=> {
            return list.includes(item.id)
        })
        setOptions(filteredOptions)
    }
```

Comment: Does useEffect call each time when you change select option value ?
if it does then you just need to pass second select code in that useEffect block.

Comment: try calling `setOptions(filteredOptions)` outside `filterOptions `

Comment: Check your ids you pass to `filterOptions`

Comment: Can you please expand the code view port for more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your primary problem is from the logic itself. `list.includes(item.id)` is checking `item.id` on `list` that always returns true.

You can modify it to `ids.includes(item.id)`

```
 const [options, setOptions] = useState<any>()
 const filterOptions = (ids: string[]) => {
        const filteredOptions = list.filter(item => {
            return ids.includes(item.id)
        })
        setOptions(filteredOptions)
    }
```

Shorter version

```
 const [options, setOptions] = useState<any>()
 const filterOptions = (ids: string[]) => {
        const filteredOptions = list.filter(item => ids.includes(item.id))
        setOptions(filteredOptions)
    }
```